# MS Access - Execute SQL statement receives error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get an error:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

...when I try to run this code:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim mySQL As String

Set db = currentdb
mySQL = "SELECT tbl1.pID, tbl1.sID, tbl1.Type, tbl1.Description, tbl1.Amount, tbl1.Delete, tbl1.Approve, tbl2.sName FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.sID = tbl1.sID WHERE pID = " & Forms.frmEdit1.cboP & " And Delete = False;"
db.Execute mySQL, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
```

It seems like the error is somewhere in the last line (that's where it fails when I use the immediate window) I also tried the single quotes around 'False'.

EDIT: Recordsource that worked

```
SELECT tbl1.[pID], 
       tbl1.[sID], 
       [tbl1].Type, 
       [tbl1].Description, 
       [tbl1].Amount, 
       [tbl1].Delete, 
       tbl1.Approve, 
       tbl2.sName 
 FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.sID = tbl1.sID 
WHERE pID = Forms![frmEdit1].cboP 
  And [Delete] = False;
```

Comment: Have you tried 0 instead of False?  Without seeing what your table data types are, the boolean can be expressed as a 0 or 1 and is worth a try.

Comment: I got it working with false now but it is not giving any results. I'm trying to populate a subform by building a SQL statement and using it as a recordsource. No success yet. The controls on my subbform are unbound.

Comment: You are missing a space just before And `Forms.[frmEdit1].cboP & "And Delete = False;"`

Comment: Yes, I caught that but still can't get any values from the query. It actually works now but doesn't return any results in my subform.

Comment: You cannot execute a select query, execute is for action queries. Just set your subform record source to the sql statement. As an aside, you should tidy your question.

Comment: Also, `Set db = CurrentDb` is a lot more common.

Comment: I did what you said but I can't get it to work. I tried this:
    Me!subP.Form.RecordSource = mySQL
Thanks for the insight into "Execute". I did not know that.

Comment: Also `Forms!frmEdit1.cboP` note ! (bang) not dot.

Comment: Yes, it works! I actually took it from the recordsource before changing things around...and I just tested it in the design window. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: So `SELECT tbl1.pID, ..., tbl2.sName FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.sID = tbl1.sID WHERE pID = Forms!frmEdit1.cboP And [Delete] = False` Delete is bracketed because it is a reserved word http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266

Comment: Added the brackets with no difference.

Comment: Please paste your current record source into your question as an edit.

Comment: Original record source? That is the revised record source! Does it work in the query design window? What is the problem in the subform?

Comment: The problem in the subform is that the SQL statement is running but not returning any values in the fields. When the subform was linked to a table it worked. But I am trying to use VBA to populate an unbound subform with a where clause based on a combobox selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, sending a SELECT statement to `Execute` is saying, 'select values according to this criteria but **don't** let me know the results', which doesn't make much sense. Populating an unbound subform needs to be done manually - that's what makes it 'unbound':

```
Sub LoadByID(Optional ByVal ID)
  Dim RS As DAO.Recordset, SQL As String
  If IsMissing(ID) Then ID = Forms!frmEdit1.cboP
  SQL = " SELECT tbl1.sID, tbl1.Type, tbl1.Description, " + _
        "        tbl1.Amount, tbl1.Delete, tbl1.Approve, tbl2.sName " + _
        " FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.sID = tbl1.sID " + _
        " WHERE pID = " & ID & " And [Delete] = False;"
  Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
  ' Assuming no match is an error; if it isn't, rewrite accordingly
  If RS.EOF Then Err.Raise 999, "LoadByID", "Er, no selection..."
  txtID.Value = RS!ID
  txtDescription.Value = RS!Description
  ' and so on...
End Sub
```

I've allowed specifying the ID not through the combo box to make the method easier to test. Also, note that if the form is supposed to allow editing, then you will need more code to then save any changed values.

**Edit**

The above was assuming only one return record. If more than one, loop like this:

```
Sub LoadByID(Optional ByVal ID)
  Dim RS As DAO.Recordset, SQL As String
  If IsMissing(ID) Then ID = Forms!frmEdit1.cboP
  SQL = " SELECT tbl1.sID, tbl1.Type, tbl1.Description, " + _
        "        tbl1.Amount, tbl1.Delete, tbl1.Approve, tbl2.sName " + _
        " FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.sID = tbl1.sID " + _
        " WHERE pID = " & ID & " And [Delete] = False;"
  Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
  ' add code to clear current display here...
  While Not RS.EOF
    ' add code to load the individual values here...
    RS.MoveNext
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Huge help! Thanks, Chris! The only thing now is that it seems to be returning the same values for each record. If the recordset query returns two records, I need each one returned. I tweeked it a bit and also added 
    RS.MoveNext
with a loop but that didn't do it.

Comment: @Brian - I've added a bit to show a loop, however I'm getting the feeling you want to recreate the functionality of a bound form...

Comment: Maybe. Can a bound form write to two separate tables? I have a join.

Comment: Create a select query that does the join, and set the form's `RecordSource` property to the name of the query.

Comment: That's what I had to begin with. I wanted to get away from bound forms because of my audit log. I need a checkbox field on the subform but don't want the record logged unless the other fields are changed (NOT the checkbox field).

Comment: Keep in mind all I have to go on is what you've previously said on this webpage - this is the first time you've mentioned an 'audit log'. If the 'checkbox field' shouldn't be bound, then surely you can just deal with it separately? In other words, bound and non-bound controls are not mutually exclusive, and you can handle appropriate form events to keep them in sync.

Comment: Thank you for that, Chris! I appreciate the time you're taking to help me. I tried to use an unbound checkbox but when I check one they all get checked. So, I'm thinking I might just use an unbound combobox unless you know how to singularly check an unbound checkbox.

Comment: I may be wrong, but my guess is you're using either the datasheet or continuous forms view, and putting the check box in the form body rather than the form header or footer.

Comment: Yes, I was using datasheet form and putting the checkbox in the Details section because there is a checkbox for each record. Is there a different way? I have an idea as a workaround to create another subform and put the two subforms side by side. Then use the second subform for the checkbox columns and not trigger the events for the audit logs.